# App Store preview video error: The frame rate of one or more of your app previews is too high

Tags: app-store, preview, submission

When I tried to upload a preview video followed by apple's guide, itunesconenct popup an error: 
[image]

Any one knows how to solve this? Thanks,

Apple's Guide:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/

Answer (score 5):

Movies in App Reviews are to have max frame rate of 30 fps. Therefore, you have to find ways to reduce your video frame rate. I reduced mine to 24 fps and got accepted by App Store. There are options as discussed below.

A. Using Terminal:

i) install ffmpeg program if you don't have:

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-chromaprint --with-fdk-aac --with-libass --with-librsvg --with-libsoxr --with-libssh --with-tesseract --with-libvidstab --with-opencore-amr --with-openh264 --with-openjpeg --with-openssl --with-rtmpdump --with-rubberband --with-sdl2 --with-snappy --with-tools --with-webp --with-x265 --with-xz --with-zeromq --with-zimg
```

ii) run ffmpeg to force changing frame rate to, 24 fps, for example.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 24 output.mp4
```

B. Using a graphical program such LumaFusion. You can buy LumaFusion and install on an iPhone/iPad, and change frame rate upon saving the video.

C. I tried to change the frame rate on iMovie, version 10.1.9, (on the Mac High Sierra 10.13.6), but there is straight forward way to change frame rate.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the official App Preview Properties: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW10

Specifically, the Max Frame Rate is **30 fps**

As you didn't mention, how you took the App Preview, I would recommend a video editing tool like iMovie, Adobe After Effects or Final Cut Pro to reduce the frame rate to the 30 fps limit.

Answer (score 0):

I use DaVinci Resolve to create previews for the App Store.

There is a free download here. https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve/.

- Set the project to the proper resolution (e.g. `866x1920` or `1080x1920`).
- Import the clip to the timeline
- `Right click` and set the clips properties to `30FPS`.
- Select `File` -> `Media Management`
- Then Transcode option
- Set the wrapper to `MP4` and the `CODEC` to `H.264`

Your clip will be exported in the proper format.